# Case_when return NA

Tags: r, dplyr, case

Could anyone tell me why the second line of code returns NA?

Best regards
Tomas

> case_when(as.numeric("80")*0.1 == 8.0 ~ TRUE)
> [1] TRUE

> case_when(as.numeric("82")*0.1 == 8.2 ~ TRUE)
> [1] NA

Comment: This is a common issue related to floating point numbers, which manifests in many languages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558

Comment: Floating points and `==` don't work well... Try `round(as.numeric("82")*0.1, 1) == 8.2`

Comment: Compare: `sprintf("%.20f",as.numeric("82")*0.1); sprintf("%.20f",8.2)`

Comment: As stated in the link that @Jon Spring posted, not every floating point number can be represented as a binary value. The value we see is not necessarily the value the computer 'sees'. You can round values, but this is often not suitable if the required level of precision exceeds the amount of rounding required to make a 'match'.. To handle this issue when performing floating point arithmetic, R has the command `all.equal()`. In your case, you could try case_when(isTRUE(all.equal(as.numeric("82")*0.1, 8.2)) ~ TRUE) although isTRUE(all.equal(as.numeric("82")*0.1, 8.2)) does the same thing.